# what is the optimal k for knn algorithm in ecommerce recommendation system

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, knn, nearest-neighbor, recommendation-engine

I'm trying to make a recommendation system in my Graduation project app using k-nearest neighbor algorithm.

I make an item recommendation system to recommend products to the active user based on products rating. 
my dataset is a matrix filled from the database, the columns represent the system's users, and the rows represent the products in the system, and the matrix filled with the rating values for each product from each user. as the following example [dataset example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmh0T.png)
, but in my case there is products not movies.

there is now 17 products(rows) and 12 users (columns). but I want an accurate general way to find k .

I wrote the following code to find k, I used k=sqrt(n)/2 as an equation to find a good k value (n represents the number of products in the application). but I want more accurate way to find the k value. so please help me.

k value:

```
 private int determineK (int n) {
        String sizeString = Integer.toString( n ) ;
        double sizeDouble = Double.parseDouble( sizeString );
       double root = Math.sqrt( sizeDouble );
        double rawK = root / 2 ;
        int num = Math.round( ( float )rawK ) ;
        if ( num%2 != 0 ) {
            return num ;
        }
        else {
            return num + 1 ;  //odd
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always find a good `k` value empirically using [cross validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)), and iterating over several values.

With cross validation with (say 10%), for each candidate of `k` you train the data on 90% of the samples, and test it on the remaining 10% (repeat 10 times, for each different "test" set for more statistically significant results).
From each candidate, you get the precision/recall curve, and can determine your best `k` based on it.

Comment: Thanks! I will learn about this method and tell you my review. Thanks a lot